# Getting random records efficiently from ArangoDB

Tags: arangodb, aql

Here is a problem I would like an efficient AQL command for.

ArangoDB 3.4.0-RC.1, RocksDB storage engine

Collection gigs has 33,000 records

I have a primary index on _key

What I want to do is the following:

I want to pull 25 random records out of the collection.

I have looked at the following things I could do:

```
FOR g IN gigs
  SORT RAND()
  LIMIT 25
  RETURN g
```

This takes on the order of 2.8 seconds on my machine.

```
RETURN NTH(gigs, 30)
```

Where 30 would be replaced by a random number.

It also takes 3 seconds.

I do not know if it is possible, but can I tell it to pick the nth record out of the primary index (the _key is all I really need)?

Any ideas on how I can get better results?

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here is, that you need to combine indices with randomness, since rocksdb doesn't have a fast way to have `any()` give you a random document in the collection.

One good approach would be to combine a random value with a range comparison, and a `LIMIT` statement:

```
FOR g IN gigs
  FILTER g.someIndexedNumber > @externalyGeneratedRandomNumber
  LIMIT 25
  RETURN g
```

You should use `explain()` to verify that your query is actually able to utilize an index.